# How to pass React props through a List Item to a class

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-props

Quick React-Native problem, how do I pass props from a class, through a **SpeciesListItem**, to **SpeciesDetail** class?

I have a class **Species** that renders a list of species which are their own **SpeciesListItem** components being passed props for rendering just fine, but when a list item is clicked, it needs to go on to the **SpeciesDetail** page with the `props` for `population`, but how do I do this last bit?

This is what I have working:

### Species

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, StyleSheet, Switch, Text, TouchableHighlight, View} from 'react-native';

import SpeciesListItem from './SpeciesListItem';

import deerData from './deerDataJson';

export default class Species extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            deerData: deerData,
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.pageContainer}>

                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SpeciesDetail')}
                                    style={styles.touchableHighlightButton}
                                    underlayColor={null}>
                    <SpeciesListItem deerData={this.state.deerData.fallowDeer}/>
                </TouchableHighlight>

            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

### SpeciesListItem

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Image, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

import colors from "../../Styles/colors";

export default class SpeciesListItem extends Component {

    deerData = this.props.deerData;

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.pageContainer}>

                {/***** Deer image *****/}
                <View style={styles.deerImageContainer}>
                    <Image style={styles.image}
                           source={this.deerData.deerImage}
                           resizeMode="center"
                    />
                </View>

                {/***** List item text *****/}
                <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.deerNameLatin}>{this.deerData.deerNameLatin}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.deerName}>{this.deerData.deerName}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.deerDescription} numberOfLines={3}>{this.deerData.ListItemDescription}</Text>
                </View>

                <Text style={styles.readMoreButton}>Read more</Text>

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

### SpeciesDetail

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class SpeciesDetail extends Component {
    render() {

        console.log('data: ', this.props.deerData);

        return (
            <ScrollView>

                <Text>{this.props.deerData.}</Text>

            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

I have removed a bunch of code for clarity as there are a number of **SpeciesListItem** components, of which I need to know which one has been selected to render the relevant data, so please, how do I pass the `props` into the **SpeciesDetail** page?

Thanks, your help with this is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: just to clarify before I answer, you are trying to pass props through `react-navigation` right?

Comment: Hi @Harrison, I'm not sure what you mean by 'through' react-navigation, but i am using it, yes. I need to go from Screen 1 (which holds a list-item component), to screen 2.

Comment: Well you are using `react-navigation` to navigate between pages and since you aren't using a framework like `redux` your best bet would be to using `react-navigation` to pass props. Give me a moment and i'll write up your solution

Comment: Okay nvm Pritish already submitted a great answer, but if you haven't looked at this page yet, you should: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that **Species** and **SpeciesDetail** are registered in *navigation stack*

You need to first wrap your `SpeciesListItem` render method into a `Touchable` object in order to access the touch events.

### SpeciesListItem

```
render() {
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress}>
    //... Other stuff
  </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

### Species

```
<SpeciesListItem onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SpeciesDetail', {deerData: this.state.deerData.fallowDeer})}
 deerData={this.state.deerData.fallowDeer}
/>
```

### SpeciesDetail

```
render() {
    /* Get the param, provide a fallback value if not available */
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const itemId = navigation.getParam('deerData', 'NO-ID');
```

The `Touchable` event should be should be relative to the component that you're pressing and not the parent, therefore remove `TouchableHighlight` from **Species**.

Comment: Thanks for this, but all I get now is that it can't read my JSON data file: 'TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.deerData.deer
NameLatin')' from my Species class

Comment: `this.deerData.deer NameLatin` probably a `.` is missing `this.deerData.deer.NameLatin`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, the dot is there: 'TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.deerData.deerNameLatin')'

Comment: Okay, if you're rendering it in the `SpeciesListItem ` then `props` is missing `this.props.deerData.deer.NameLatin`, in the parent `this.state.deerData.NameLatin`, check the logs it will show you correct values of the json

Comment: I haven't even tried to render anything in the detail page yet. This is being thrown when trying to open the Species page

Comment: Updated, I suppose I had removed the `deerData` which was being passed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180476/discussion-between-pritish-vaidya-and-richard-kemikal-general-denton).

Comment: Thanks Pritish, I needed to add parenthesis to the SpeciesListItem `onPress={this.props.onPress}` to `onPress={this.props.onPress()}`

Answer (score 1):

React Navigation has a great way to pass parameters to routes when you navigate to them.

In your Species file (or wherever you use `this.props.navigation.navigate`), you can pass extra parameters to the navigate function like so:

`this.props.navigation.navigate('SpeciesDetail', { deerData: this.state.deerData })`

Then, in your SpeciesDetail file, you can access the navigation parameters like so (replacing your references to `this.props.deerData`):

`this.props.navigation.getParam('deerData')`

More information on this subject can be found in the [React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link dude :)